# How to copy Range Array to specific destination in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Please help I've search everywhere but it seems all methods failed. This is my Code

```
Dim MyArray(1 To 20) As Range
Dim A0 As Integer
Cells(1, 1).Select

For A0 = 1 To 20
Set MyArray(A0) = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next



Range("A15:T15") = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
Range("A15:T16") = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
Range("A15:T15") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)
Range("A15:T16") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)
```

I've tried every last 4 procedure/s. But failed. This is just summary to make it east to read. Thanks

Comment: What is it meant to do? What is it currently doing? Have you run through the code to find what line has the error [if there is an error?]

Comment: each of the last 4 procedures I've tried one by one, but all are wrong because it will not copy the data of MyArray  to ranges starting from range("A15")

Comment: Have you tries it without `Transpose`? 1D arrays are horizontal ... you only transpose when you want them to be vertical.

Comment: MyArray consists of 2rows and 20columns. I've tried 1row and it worked

Comment: Your array consists of 20 columns and 1 row. You need to declare your array `Dim MyArray(1 To 20, 1 To 2) as Range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going a bit further than my comment ... try this as an example ...

```
Sub a()

Dim x(2) As Integer
x(0) = 1
x(1) = 2

Range("A10:B10").Value = x

End Sub
```

This correctly outputs the array into cells `A10` and `B10`

---

In the case of a 2D array, you can use this example ...

```
Sub a()

Dim x(2,2) As Integer
x(0,0) = 1
x(0,1) = 2
x(1,0) = 3
x(1,1) = 4

Range("A10:B11").Value = x

End Sub
```

You still don't need transpose though!

Comment: thanks guys. now it works. I need to declare it as a 2 dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

You can move data from "Range to Array" and "Array to Range" using only one line for each operation.

```
Sub CopyUsingArray()

    ' Create array
    Dim Marks() As Variant

    ' Read 20 values into array from sheet1
    Marks = Range("A1:T1").Value

    ' Write the 20 values to row 15
    Range("A15:T15").Value = Marks

End Sub
```

Of course, if you are simply copying from on range to another you don't need to use an array. You can use the Range.Copy method like so

```
Sub CopyRange()

    Range("A1:T1").Copy Destination:=Range("A15")

End Sub
```

If you need to Transpose the data you can do it this way

```
Sub CopyRange_Transpose()

    Range("A1:T1").Copy
    Range("A15").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```